# continue to check all instances version even one raise an error in python?

Tags: windows-10, python-3.8

I have a function in which I am trying to get the version of the db's.i have multiple instances and I am able to connect with all of them.Problem I am facing if any db doesn't connect or command fails for some reason it doesn't continue to next db.All I want it to continue till last instance

```
def dbversion(user_suffix=None):
    try:
        db_name_list = abc.getdbstring(env_name=None)
        for dbname in db_name_list:
            connection = Connection(dbname)
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            version = connection.version
            print(" " + version + " ")
    except:
        print("Fail")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `try` block within the loop:

```py
def dbversion(user_suffix=None):
    db_name_list = abc.getdbstring(env_name=None)
    for dbname in db_name_list:
        try:
            connection = Connection(dbname)
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            version = connection.version
            print(" " + version + " ")
        except:
            print("Fail")
```

Comment: can we catch the real exception and continue?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. You can do something like `except Exception as e: print(e)` to get more information